# android non activity

Tags: android

how to create a class which not extended Activity & how can i use it class?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want but a regular class would be

```
public class Name {}
```

and then

```
Name name = new Name()
```

*edit:
Works just like Java on you computer